# How to convert a Flux<List<T>> to a merged Flux<T>?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactor

While working with Project Reactor, there came a use case where I'd want to convert a Flux <List<String>> to a <Flux<String>> where all those lists are flattened to form a Flux. Is there any out of the box method for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)`

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
var flux = Flux.just(list)
            .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable);
```